# what is the Integral of Exponential function??

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, exponential-function

I need to calculate the integral of

$$\int_{0}^{u}e^{-\alpha t-\frac{\beta}{t}}dt$$

From one book I came to knnow

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha t-\frac{\beta}{4t}}dt = \sqrt{\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}K_1(\sqrt{\beta\alpha}) $$

where $K_1(.)$ is first order modified Bessel function of second kind.

Comment: I am afraid that there is probably no closed form for it.

Comment: May be too puristic but (at least for me) $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha t-\frac{\beta}{4t}}\,dt =\frac{\sqrt{\beta } K_1\left(\sqrt{\alpha } \sqrt{\beta }\right)}{\sqrt{\alpha }}$$ provided that $\Re(\beta )>0\land \Re(\alpha )>0$

Comment: So: Marcus knows the definite integral from $0$ to $\infty$, and he wants the integral from $0$ to $u$, essentially he wants the indefinite integral.